# C# - How to show process progress percentage & print a changing string on a Console App?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I would like to know if there is a way to do two things in a Console App for C# Code.

First one, is to show the progress percentage of a called process, so that, the user will will know more or less the elapsed progress and how much he/she needs to wait.

Second one, is to print three strings which constantly change, looping each one, until the process finishes.

Those are the Strings I would like to Print, one after another, but on the Same Line of the Console App Screen:

```
string Please_Wait_One_Dot = "Please wait.";
string Please_Wait_Two_Dots = "Please wait..";
string Please_Wait_Three_Dots = "Please wait...";

Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", Please_Wait_One_Dot);
Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", Please_Wait_Two_Dots);
Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", Please_Wait_Three_Dots);

// This Prints those Strings but on Different Lines without any Loop.
```

Basically, what I want to do is to Print some Text which shows an Message but, the Number of Dots Changes from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 and then it Changes back to 1, Looping this Cycle until the Selected Operation by the User is Finally Done.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a for/while loop?

Comment: Are you imagining some kind of animation? Like, the three dots overwrite each other at the same position on your console window? My advice: do not do this. Make console applications output only the end result, like command-line tools do. Console output should be useful if piped to a file or other non-interactive data sink.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do something like that but without any animation played, just the dots overwriting on a same position and after the process is finished, it shows the Result.

Comment: The console class has a [SetCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-5.0) method

Comment: Will check out on a while, thanks!

Comment: Use ` \r ` instead so it stays on one line.  ` \b \b ` is a standard trick to erase a character.

Answer (score 0):

NOT TESTED... use as pseudo code...

```
Console.write("Please_Wait");
int count = 0;
do
{
   if (count < 3)  
   {
      Console.Write(".");  // add a dot
      count++;
   }
   else
   {
     Console.Write("\b\b\b");  // erase all dots
     count = 0;                //resume   
   } 
   
} while(not_done)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it and tell you if it works.

Comment: know that I did not include any timing/delays... so this will fire pretty fast ... probably hard to see on screen...

Comment: By the way, what's the type of the variable not_done and its Equivalence? It says it doesn't exists.

Comment: a pysuedo reference to your statement "
 Looping this Cicle until the Selected Operation by the User is Finally Done.

This just needs a boolean expression resolved by when the user does his thing..